# Количество вхождений подстроки

Tags: c#

Даны строки S и S0. Найти количество вхождений строки S0 в строку S.

Comment: Оценка скорости предложенных методов:
Split - самый быстрый;
Replace - в 3 раза медленней;
Regex - самый медленный (в 10 раз от Split).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
private int CountWords(string s, string s0)
{
    int count = (s.Length - s.Replace(s0, "").Length) / s0.Length;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: так просто что ли?

Comment: средствами языка всегда проще :)

Comment: Эм.. А сколько раз строка `aa` входит в строку `aaa`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, адын.

Answer (score 12):

Используя регулярные выражения (pattern - что ищем, source - где ищем):

```
int amount = new Regex(pattern).Matches(source).Count;
```

Comment: Плюсуюсь за регулярки

Comment: Решение - просто бомба!

Answer (score 2):

```
private Int32 CountWords(String S, String S0)
{
    String[] temp = S0.Split(new[] { S }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    return temp.Length - 1;
}
```